# Bundle.main.path(forResource... always returns nil when looking for xml file

Tags: swift, xml, bundle, filepath

I am trying to read a file from my bundle. I know this has been asked before but I have read the other SO solutions and not of them seem to be of my situation.

I have an XML file. I can see it in the project navigator:

[image]

and I can also check that it is included in the bundle by going to Project/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resource

[image]

I've tried to get its path using the file manager with no luck, using inDirectory and not using inDirectory:

```
 let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "config", ofType: "xml", inDirectory:"Resources")
```

I'm kind of at a loss as to what to try next.

Edit:

I got it to work but this seems to be way more code than I should need.

```
let arrFiles = getAllFiles()
        let fileName = strFileName + "." + strFileExtension

        for thisObj in arrFiles {
            if thisObj == "config.xml" {

                let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: thisObj, ofType: nil)
                print(filePath)
            }

        }
```

Comment: Try this directly, instead of looping and all. It will work directly. 
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "config.xml", ofType: nil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "config.xml", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "/Resources") {

   /// Do something with the filePath

}
```

Comment: After changing my resources directory path, the subdirectory specification helped.. thanks!