# Loading txt file resources in Xcode workspace

Tags: swift, xcode, server, xcode-workspace

I have a txt file that loads fine in the client app using:

```
let fileURLProject = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "txt")
       
do {
    let data = try String(contentsOfFile: fileURLProject!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch (etc..)
```

But when adding the same file to the server target (SwiftWebSocketServer in the same Xcode project workspace), the do statement breaks.  I tried many solutions including:

[Bundle.main.path(forResource... always returns nil when looking for xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51875058/bundle-main-pathforresource-always-returns-nil-when-looking-for-xml-file)

[Load txt file Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034300/load-txt-file-swift)

But thinking has to do with adding it to Target --> Build Phases --> ? ..
Tried adding it to the compile source (doesn't work out), moving the file to root, into folders (groups and references), thinking it has something to do with adding to Target --> Build Phases --> 'copy files', but not sure of the destination/path etc.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what "the server target" is, but if it's a command-line tool you are building, it has no bundle and there is no way to include any ancillary files "in" it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Under the Products folder it says 'Exec', guess this means it's a package, i.e. no bundle structure

Comment: Sounds to me like it confirms what I suggested, that this is a command line tool. But you are really not giving enough info. You should know what your own project consists of!